# Fade out picture on mouseover and then fade in different picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

was wondering if it is possible to:

- Fade out picture on mouseover AND then fade in different picture after the first fade out.

Fade out is easy with:

```
   .overlay {
   position: absolute; width: 269px;  height: 344px;   bottom:0;
   left: 6%;   z-index: 2;   transition: opacity 1.5s ease;  opacity:1;
   }

  .overlay:hover {  opacity:0;  }
```

The pictures are of different size.

Comment: Completely fade out and then fade in on the same mouseover.

Comment: Yes, it is...what have you tried? Could you make a JSfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to use a pure jQuery method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changed = false;
    $( ".overlay" ).mouseover(function() {
        if(!changed) {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0, function() {
                $(this).children('img').attr("src", "newjpg.jpg");
                $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
            });
            changed = true;
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8pFBB/

---

**EDIT: With ability to revert to old image & queueing to prevent animations from stacking indefinitely when moving mouse over and away from object repeatedly**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".overlay").queue("fadeFx");
    var fading = false;
    $(".overlay").mouseover(function() {
        if(fading) { $(".overlay").dequeue(); }
        fading = true;
        $(this).fadeTo( "slow" , 0, function() {
            $(this).children('img').attr("src", "http://placehold.it/350x150");
            $(this).fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
            fading = false;
        });
    });
    $(".overlay").mouseout(function() {
        if(fading) { $(".overlay").dequeue(); }
        fading = true;
        $(this).fadeTo( "slow" , 0, function() {
            $(this).children('img').attr("src", "http://placehold.it/150x350");
            $(this).fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
            fading = false;
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8uVHF/

Comment: this does nothing also :(

Comment: @user3524419 Updated and tested with jsFiddle.

Comment: Very well, but I'd like for 350x150 to revert back again to 150x350 whenever the mouse is not over it.

Comment: @user3524419 Don't have a very elegant way of handling when the user mouseover and mouseouts several times repeatedly. But currently it at least dequeues the animation otherwise your image could stay hidden for a long time. (Comment out the two `if(fading)` lines and `$(".overlay").queue("fadeFx");` to see what I mean)

Answer (score 2):

This should work and allow you to do it completely in jquery

```
$( ".overlay" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0, function() {
    $( this ).attr("src", newIMGURL);
        $( this ).fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
  });
});
```

The issue with the other answer is it will change the img while it is still fading, which will not look pleasant, on mine it waits until the image has fully faded out to switch the image, then fades back in.

Comment: Allright, I remove CSS, add this to header and replace newIMGof URL with the path my second image, right?

Comment: Yup, and if you are adding it to the header make sure to put it in a <script> tag. Also make sure it is placed after you are importing jQuery. If you arent already importing it just place <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> before my code.

Comment: Well, doesn't work..Im trying it on my PC, not on server.. Nothing happesns really, Im using jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: In that case try `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>` instead

Comment: Still, nothing.
    <script>
    $( ".overlay" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0, function() {
    $( this ).attr("src", C:/Users/me/Desktop/sponge/game.jpg);
    $( this ).fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
    });
    });
    </script>
dammit :(

Comment: Well you need to wrap the image link in quotes, you also want to use relative links instead of absolute links, so if your html file is in the sponge folder then just use "game.jpg" instead of C:/Users/me/Desktop/sponge/game.jpg

Comment: :( urgh nothing happens

Comment: In the browser go to your console and tell me what you see.

Comment: With 1.11.0/jquery.min.js the console is empty while with 1.2.1 it says jquery not defined and $ not defined in your given code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.overlay').hover(function() {
$(this).fadeOut();
$(this).attr('src', 'newImage.png');
}
```